# тип возвращаемого значения typeid(value).name()

Tags: c++

Есть некий кусок кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {

  int a = 5;
  std::string check = "int";

  if (typeid(a).name() == check)
    std::cout << "check variable works" << std::endl;

  if (typeid(a).name() == "int")
    std::cout << "just string works" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

В первом варианте, где проверка с переменной check - условие сработает, во втором - нет.
Если сделать просто вывод

```
std::cout << typeid(a).name();
```

тот выведет строку `"int"`.

Почему так происходит, если по-сути мы сравниваем с одним и тем же значением?

Comment: http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strcmp.html

Comment: [Не надо так сравнивать](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name). Используйте `decltype` и `std::is_same`

Answer (score 3):

[`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) возвращает `const char*`([строку в стиле C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), *указатель*)

Сравнение с `check` работает, так как `std::string` имеет перегруженный [оператор сравнения](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

`"int"` имеет тип `const char[4]` и сравнение с ним равносильно сравнению указателей.

Для сравнения строк в стиле C используется функция [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score 2):

Почему так происходит, объяснено в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175990/398802) участника [@Maxim Timakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209264/maxim-timakov). Добавлю, что если вашим намерением было сравнение типов, то стоит делать это так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  int a = 5;
  constexpr int b = 42;  

  if (std::is_same_v<decltype(a), int>) {
    std::cout << "ok\n";
  }
    
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(b), const int>) {
    std::cout << "ok\n";
  }
}
```